# FileUpload returns null/Empty in GridView's RowUpdate event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload, code-behind

```
Problem:
```

FileUpload's File name not accessible inGridView

```
Explanation:
```

I have FileUpload in GridView, On GridView RowUpdate, i select a file in FileUpload, but when I couldn't get file Name in GridView's Rowupdate.

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Report">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:FileUpload ID="fuMaintenanceScanedReport" runat="server" Width="248px" Font-Size="Smaller"  EnableViewState="true"/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuMaintenanceScanedReport" runat="server" Width="248px" Font-Size="Smaller" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="250px" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is my Code behind code

```
protected void GvSchedule_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileUpload = ((FileUpload)GvSchedule.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("fuMaintenanceScanedReport")).FileName;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have an EditItemTemplate for a column that only contains a FileUpload control? Are you sure you are in edit mode when uploading the file?

Comment: Yes, i want to get value in edit mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Update Panel, and due to that it was not posting back FileUpload server control, that is why not getting files.

```
I simply remove the Update panel
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in updatepanel inside gridview and add trigers for that.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UploadImage">

   <ItemTemplate>

      <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/1.jpg" runat="server" ID="image" /> // shown only when not in edit mode

    </ItemTemplate>

   <EditItemTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> // shown only in edit mode
<asp:Button ID="GridUploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="GridUploadButton_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>                                                                  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridUploadButton" />
</Triggers>

   </EditItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
```